# unexpected token " in pug before body tag

Tags: html, express, pug

Pug is ridiculous, I can't spot the error at all. Below is my full pug file.

```
html
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible",content="IE=edge")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
        script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js")
        script(src="ga.js")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/4.0.2/bootstrap-material-design.min.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="app.css")
        title= "my title"
    body                        
        .container
            .row
                .col-md-12
                    h1="My h1 tag"
```

Comment: The current NPM version of Pug has no issues with that template whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "=" on those lines : `title= "my title"` should be `title my title` and `h1="My h1 tag"` should be `h1 My h1 tag`